# Need The answer for using the logic of quick sort in set Interval

Tags: javascript

Hi all I' tried ou this logic for quick sort program . But I need to convert this code to set Interval mode and need to cover the total process step by step. Please Help me in improving this logic to an setinterval Program . I think currently it's in recursive mode.

```
function quicksort(arr)
{
    if (arr.length == 0)
        return [];

    var left = new Array();
    var right = new Array();
    var pivot = arr[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) {
           left.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
           right.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return quicksort(left).concat(pivot, quicksort(right));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to set Interval mode"? `setInterval` is used to run the same function every N miliseconds. quicksort is inherently a recursive algorithm. If you want to perform the sort in the background, without blocking the UI, you need to convert the recursive algorithm to continuation-passing style. Then you can use `setTimeout` to call the continuation after a timeout. See [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/) for how to write CPS in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert quicksort to a non-recursive format (iterative quicksort) and then use setInterval to replace the for loop, therefore converting the original quicksort to "setInterval mode".

Here's iterative quicksort from [Stoimen's blog](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/18/friday-algorithms-iterative-quicksort/) (I believe that your original recursive quicksort [comes from the same source](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/11/friday-algorithms-quicksort-difference-between-php-and-javascript/)). Note that I've modified it slightly so that it uses a callback in continuation-passing style rather than `return`:

```
function qsort(arr, ret)
{
    var stack = [arr];
    var sorted = [];

    while (stack.length) {

        var temp = stack.pop(), tl = temp.length;

        if (tl == 1) {
            sorted.push(temp[0]);
            continue;
        }
        var pivot = temp[0];
        var left = [], right = [];

        for (var i = 1; i < tl; i++) {
            if (temp[i] < pivot) {
                left.push(temp[i]);
            } else {
                right.push(temp[i]);
            }
        }

        left.push(pivot);

        if (right.length)
            stack.push(right);
        if (left.length)
            stack.push(left);

    }

    ret(sorted);
}
```

You can call the function this way (for example):

`qsort([3,7,1,4,2,5], function(sortedarray) { console.log(sortedarray); });`

Now to convert this iterative quicksort to "setInterval mode" you could replace the for loop in the function with calls to setInterval (similar to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323685/can-you-use-setinterval-to-call-functions-asynchronously)).

Here's the final version of quicksort using `setInterval`:

```
function qsort(arr, ret)
{
    var stack = [arr];
    var sorted = [];
    var intervalId = 0;

    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (stack.length) { 
            var temp = stack.pop(), tl = temp.length;

            if (tl == 1) {
                sorted.push(temp[0]);
                return;
            }
            var pivot = temp[0];
            var left = [], right = [];

            for (var i = 1; i < tl; i++) {
                if (temp[i] < pivot) {
                    left.push(temp[i]);
                } else {
                    right.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }

            left.push(pivot);

            if (right.length)
                stack.push(right);
            if (left.length)
                stack.push(left);           
        } 
        else if (sorted.length == arr.length) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            ret(sorted);
        }
    }, 0);      
}
```

What happens here is that pieces of your original array are being added to the stack (this is the partitioning step) and then individually sorted. At every `setInterval` call you are sorting a different piece of the array (in the original recursive quicksort, every quicksort call was dealing with a different piece of the array). Note that we stop sorting (that is, we tell `setInterval` to stop making calls) once sorted array is of the same size as the original. That's when we call our `ret` callback.